# React Native Ios error 'failed to load bundle'

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to start learn React-Native

```
react-native init
react-native run-ios
```

[image]
I have tried four methods of image

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't install babel. Please try.

```
npm install babel
```

Then run project again by `npm start`

If it doesn't work, you can `npm start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

Is your packager running ?

What you could do is restart your packager and rebuild your nodejs with `rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn start`. Then, you can run your application with `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm add @babel/runtime
npm install
```

Then in the main directory, just use `react-native run-ios` and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

hi, Welcome to Stackoverflow

I also had the same problem. Try this out.It worked for me.

1. close your existing metro app.
2. install these two packages

   `npm install --save-dev @babel/core`
   `npm install --save-dev @babel/runtime`

   If you are using yarn instead of npm use below commands

   `yarn add --dev @babel/core`
      `yarn add --dev @babel/runtime`
3. then run this command.
   `react-native start --reset-cache`
4. Open another terminal tab and run your ios app 
   `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions above, but none worked. But this solution works in my case (React-Native 0.57.2) :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490#issuecomment-427240356

1.Close all Metro Bundler running

2.Clean the cache

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all
```

3.Create a new project and install babel runtime

```
react-native init awesomeproject
cd awesomeproject
npm install --save-dev @babel/runtime
```

3.Start Metro Bundler in your terminal (don't close it)

```
react-native start
```

4.Open a new window in your terminal,and run your app

```
react-native run-ios
```